# What's the class equivalent of instancesRespondToSelector?

Tags: ios, nsobject

What's the simplest way to check if a **class method** is implemented by a class?

For example, UIFont defines this method:

```
+ (UIFont *)preferredFontForTextStyle:(NSString *)style NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0);
```

I cannot use `instancesRespondToSelector:` here, as `preferredFontForTextStyle:` is not an instance method but a class method.

I see `class_getClassMethod`, but… really? objc/runtime.h?

Comment: Just message the metaclass. `[[[UIFont class] class] instancesRespondToSelector:]`, etc. BTW, **what's wrong with using the runtime library for... a *runtime* task?**

Comment: The metaclass is a great answer; if you post it I'll accept it immediately. (And nothing. I use it when I have to; It's just a lower level of abstraction. If I was satisfied with it, I wouldn't've discovered the metaclass today. Thanks!)

Comment: Actually, I take it back. It doesn't seem to work in this case.

Comment: You're welcome. -- It should work, maybe it's just that `- class` is broken. Could you try messaging `object_getClass([UIFont class])` and see if it works? I have memories about `class` not returning the expected class...

Comment: You're dead on. `[[UIFont class] class]` returns UIFont; `object_getClass([UIFont class])` returns a `Class` without a debug description. Interestingly, they both respond to `description` with `UIFont`, but they're different things. Definitely learning stuff today. :)

Comment: Right. `[UIFont class]` is already the class itself. Calling `class` on it just returns itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd use:

```
[MyClass respondsToSelector:mySelector]
```

All classes are instances of the base class. So all of NSObject's instance methods are also class methods for any class which derives from NSObject.

It makes some intuitive sense. Classes are objects, after all, so all of NSObject's methods make sense on classes.

If you're curious about why this happens in more detail, read up on [metaclasses in Objective-C](http://www.sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2009/04/14/objc_explain_Classes_and_metaclasses.html).

The reason that `[[MyClass class] instancesRespondToSelector:mySelector]` doesn't work is that [NSObject actually defines `+class` to return self](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-532/runtime/NSObject.mm). Metaclasses are hidden from view by the frameworks and only accessible via the runtime API.

Comment: `[[[UIFont alloc] init] respondsToSelector:@selector(preferredFontForTextStyle:)]` and `[UIFont instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(preferredFontForTextStyle:)]` are both `NO`.

Comment: Try `[UIFont respondsToSelector:@ selector(preferredFontForTextStyle:)]`

Comment: Aha! Now I understand. Thanks. Can I suggest changing `myClass` to `MyClass`, though? `myClass` looks like an instance by convention. :)

Comment: I was worried I was posting a dumb question, but an answer like the made it worthwhile. :)